# Вложенная таблица

Tags: html5, css3

Появилась необходимость сделать таблицу вложенной. Как изменить ширину конкретной ячейки в конкретной строке? пытался задавать через атрибут width для тега td, но меняется ширина всех первых ячеек.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

как вариант не таблицу сделать а div

```
<div style="width:250px;">
 <div style="width:30%;"></div>
 <div style="width:30%;"></div>
 <div style="width:40%;"></div>
</div>
```